# Changing td color if its value is over 10,000

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, css-selectors

I'm am doing the CS50 finance exercise and I am trying to display whether someone has made a profit with his stocks. Initially, you get 10000 cash. I am trying to display when the total value (end of the HTML code) of the portfolio surpasses the 10000 dollars. I have wrote the following code, it is not working yet however, hope you can help me.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id td.color').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() > 10000) {
        $(this).css('color', '#2e944b');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<table class="table" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Current Price</th>
    <th>Holdings</th>
  </tr>
  {% for port in portfolio %}
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{port.id}}</td>
    <td>{{port.stocks}}</td>
    <td>{{lookup(port.stocks)['name']}}</td>
    <td>{{port.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{usd(lookup(port.stocks)['price'])}}</td>
    <td>{{usd(lookup(port.stocks)['price']*port.amount)}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
    <td><b>Cash</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ usd(cash) }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="color">{{ usd(grand_tot) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Output value screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that jQuery 1.4.4 is very outdated. You should be using at least 1.12.1, ideally 3.3.1 (at time of this question).

The main issue with your logic is that you're using `val()` on a `td` element which does not have a value. You need to check the `text()` instead. Given the formatting of the text you will also need to remove the `$` and `,` characters from it before making the comparison.

Also note that it's better practice to apply classes to elements to style them, to maintain a separation of concerns. As such you can use `addClass()`, and you can provide a function to that method call to determine if the class should be added or not based on the text in the cell.

Finally note that the question states 'over 10,000', yet your code is checking for over 1,000. Either way, it's a simple change in the logic. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_id td.color').addClass(function() {
    var total = $(this).text().replace(/[$,]/g, '');
    return parseInt(total, 10) > 10000 ? 'foo' : null;
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: #2E944B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table_id">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Current Price</th>
    <th>Holdings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="color">$101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="color">$1,001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="color">$10,001</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="color">$100,001</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Rory, Thanks for that very clear asnwer. One additional question: because I pass the value through a function that makes it dollar notation, turning it green does not seem to work. The code for this function is very simple:     return f"${value:,.2f}"

Any suggestions how I might work around this?

Comment: You just need to remove the `$` before you do the calculation: `parseInt($(this).text().replace('$', ''), 10)`

Comment: mmm, I am afraid that is not working for me. I have also tried replacing the $ with a 0 but that neither does it. Sorry to bother, thanks for helping. Also, would you mind specifying in the original post what the ten in '), 10)' and the 'null' do in your jQuery code? I'm rather new to this

Comment: Could you show me an example of the actual output value. The `10` is the radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax

Comment: I have added a screenshot, hope this is what you meant. @Rory

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the answer. For future reference it's always worth showing the actual HTML output instead of a template which is open to interpretation

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for the value of a `td` by doing `if ($(this).val() > 1000) {`.  But the `td` does not have a value, it has a text inside it. You therefor need to check against the `.text()` method, not the `.val()` method.

```
$('#table_id td.color').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() > 1000) {
        $(this).css('color','#2e944b');
    }
});
```

Comment: you are comparing string with integer

Comment: Try it out, `10 > "11"` works fine. Though parsing it as an int could be a good thing, that was not the actual issue. Btw, you should add some description with your answer, not just "this will work", otherwise someone might downvote you too, for having a non-descriptive answer.. ;-) Code-only answers are generally not appreciated.

Comment: @AmoghHegde it's called type coercion.  It's been around for a very long time and causes a lot of people that don't understand it to think it's a mistake.

Comment: Okk sorry for the mistake.. tried it myself, i'll remove the downvote..
Edit: oops too late 5 mins up sorry..

Answer (score 0):

This should work considering the value is always `Integer`

`val()` method works only for input fields, to get the inner html of a `<td>` you need to use `text()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_id td.color').each(function(){
        if (parseInt($(this).text()) > 1000) {
            $(this).css('color','#2e944b');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `$(this).val()`. The `<td>` tag not has `val()`

```html
<style></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_id td.color').each(function(){        
        if ($(this).html() > 1000) {
            $(this).css('color','#2e944b');
        }
    });
});
</script>
  <table class="table" id="table_id" >
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>Holdings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="color">900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Total</b></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="color">1001</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```